# Command not found systemctl on Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, kibana

I get `bash: systemctl: command not found`. I suspect maybe I am running with **Amazon Linux**, not **Amazon Linux 2**.

I am running the below command:

```
systemctl enable logstash-node
```

Comment: Can you check if you run Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

To know the version of linux use this

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

like you said  If it is Amazon linux version 1, then it doesn't support systemctl cause Amazon Linux is ultimately based on an old version of CentOS/RHEL.

In AmazonLinux1, use chkconfig command.

```
$ sudo chkconfig mysqld on
$ sudo chkconfig httpd on
```

for more [usage of chkconfig](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-service-on-boot-with-chkconfig/)